# What is particle-hole symmetry for Bose-Hubbard model (if there is)?

Tags: condensed-matter, bose-hubbard-model

When people talking about particle-hole symmetry on Bose-Hubbard model, one always considers single particle and single hole excitations on Mott-insulator phase:
$$
E_{\mathbf{q}}^{\pm}=\pm \omega_{\mathbf{q}}^{\pm}=\pm\left(-\mu+\frac{U}{2}(2 \bar{n}-1)-\frac{\epsilon_{\mathbf{q}}}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\epsilon_{\mathbf{q}}^2-2(2 \bar{n}+1) U \epsilon_{\mathbf{q}}+U^2}
$$
However, they just look like properties on excitations. Is there any symmetry transform like particle-hole transform on Bose-Hubbard model Hamiltonian, similar with half-filling Fermi-Hubbard model?

Edit: There are some arguments in Phys. Rev. Lett. 76, transform $n_{i}\rightarrow n_{0}+n_{i}$ would make original Hamiltonian invariant up to a constant. I hope for some better comments and instructions.